# How to get object name by queryset in django

Tags: django

Is there any attribute or method to get objects'name by queryset in django
I have some code like this

```
# in views.py
product = []
product.append(Pc.objects.filter(user__name=pk))  ## user is a foreignkey
product.append(Monitor.objects.filter(user__name=pk))
arr = { 'type': 1,
        'product': product,
        'name': name,
         }   
return render_to_response('list.html', arr)
```

In template list.html

```
......
 <tbody>
       {% for pr in product %}  
       <tr style="text-align:center" class="form-inline">
       <td>
       {{ name }}
       </td>
       {% for p in pr %}
       <td>
           {{ p.number }}
       </td>
       <td>
           {{ p.product }}
       </td>
       <td>
           {{ p.comment }}
       </td>
       <td>                                                                                                                                                                               
           <a href="/update/objects/{{ p.id }}/" class="btn btn-success btn-sm" >edit</a>
           <a href="/delete/objects/{{ p.id }}/" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure to delete?')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" >delete</a>
       </td>
       {% endfor %}
       {% endfor %}
       </tr>
  </tbody>
```

How should I get the "objects" like Pc or Monitor in list.html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of trying to get the type and then displaying the class name in the template why don't you just add a static attribute to the classes?

```
class Pc(models.Model):
   product_display_name = 'PC'

class Monitor(models.Model):
   product_display_name = 'Monitor'
```

Then in the template

```
{% for p in pr %}
<td>
    {{ p.product_display_name }}
</td>
<td>
    {{ p.number }}
</td>
{% endfor %}
```

If you would really like to get the name from the type then you can use the following

```
type(instance).__name__
```

Comment: It's one method to get object's name by add display_name when define the objects.I'm a new django learner,and I think I have a long way to go.